# reading a file which is locked by other process

Tags: java, perl, file, io

I have one doubt that one perl process is writing in one file and same file is being read by a java thread. Suppose if that thread access that file to read it at the time when perl process is writing in it then , will thread will go to waiting state or will be able to read it.
It it goes to waiting state then , will it return back to running state or will go for waiting state forever. How actually 2 different process will do it.

Hi , Actually i have 2 process. one is perl process , which is slower one , which updates the file continuously whenever one task gets complete to update status of that task as successful or failed.  Other is Java process which reads from this file continuously whether task status is successful or failed. So since java process is  fast process (as it need not to wait for any task to complete) , so now what will be scenario. Will this java thread will go to waiting state or terminating state when file is being locked by perl process for writing. OS is linux.

Comment: What did you find when trying to access one?

Comment: are you familiar with file locking in general? (acquiring exclusive/shared && blocking/non blocking locks?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the file at the same time it is being read, it is better to do it atomically (write a new version under different name, then merge its contents or rename it later on).

However, you need to make sure that there is only one process which is updating it at any given point of time (the perl script, in this case), or there could be a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

You may also want to read up on [unix file-locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Unix-like_systems) in general.